# Circle functions not behaving as expected in Java Class

Tags: java, class, methods, public

so i made a circle class that sets the radius, and should output the radius, circumference and area however, if i input the radius, the radius, circumference, area wont output back, it just shows as 0.0
heres my Circle.java

```
public class Circle
{
    private double radius;
    private double PI = 3.14159;

    public void setRadius(double rad)
    {
            radius = rad;
    }

    public double getRadius()
    {
            return radius;
    }

    public double getArea()
    {
            return PI * radius * radius;
    }

    public double getDiameter()
    {
            return 2 * radius;
    }

    public double getCircumference()
    {
            return 2 * PI * radius;
    }

}
```

and heres circledemo.java
http://pastie.org/466414
-formatting didnt come out well here

First I input the radius, but when i call getRadius, circumference, area, it just outputs 0.0

Comment: Probably the formatting didn't come out well because you indented with tabs instead of spaces.

Comment: So.... what does it output that's wrong??

Comment: so i input the radius, but when i call getRadius,circumference, area, it just outputs 0.0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's walk through the program execution, step by step. First, you initialize some variables and then create a Scanner object. Next, you enter a `while` loop. Inside that while loop, you display the main menu, read input from the keyboard, **create a new Circle object**, and then handle the input you received. And you keep doing that until `flag` is set to `false`, in which case the program exits.

Notice anything strange here?

A variable only exists inside the scope it was declared in, and your Circle object was declared *inside* the while loop. Remember, the body of a while loop represents ***one iteration*** of a while loop. So, essentially, your Circle object is getting re-created over and over again, which is why `setRadius()` is having no effect.

Comment: A good rule of thumb is that each time you see a {, you're entering a new scope, and each time you see a }, you're leaving it. Meaning that anything declared inside a pair of {}'s, goes out of scope when you get to the }. I might be oversimplifying a little bit, but that gives you the right idea I think.

Also, it's a good idea to increase your indentation at every {, and then decrease it at every }.

Comment: @Raptrex It is a courtesy that if @htw's answer was the answer you Accept as correct for you to mark the answer as "Accepted" (by clicking the checkmark next to the answer).

Answer (score 1):

Create the Circle object instance (i.e the code Circle one = new Circle()) OUTSIDE of the while loop. Every iteration of the loop is causing the object to be re-created with new state (i.e. new radius).